# Uniform surface distribution using radial function

Tags: 3d, uniform-distribution

I have a problem where I want to describe a uniform distrubution on a random 3D surface. Suppose I have given a star-convex surface by means of a radial function
\begin{equation}
r=f(\theta,\phi)
\end{equation}
with elevation $\theta$, azimuth $\phi$ and radius $r$. Thus, for every angle pair $[\theta,\phi]^T\in[0,\pi)\times[0,2\pi)$ a radius is given by function f describing a point on a surface in spherical coordinates. Is there an analytical way to describe a uniform distribution of points on the surface imposed by the radial function?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you take probability density of proportional to the metrics, you will get the uniform distribution. For spherical coordinates:

$$
\omega(\theta,\phi) \propto g = \left|\begin{pmatrix}r\\ 0 \\\partial r/\partial \theta\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}0\\ r\cos\theta \\\partial r/\partial \phi\end{pmatrix}\right|.
$$

If you integrate $\omega(\theta,\phi)$ over any region, it will be proportional to the area of the region by design, which is the definition of uniform distribution.